# Moving clients from Outlook Express/POP3 to Outlook/IMAP or Exchange

Tags: windows, exchange, outlook, imap

I have a client that is still running outlook express with XP and on POP3 based e-mail. I've not played with Exchange or IMAP much but would it be possible to import all their addresses, folders, and emails from OE to a more modern email protocol? Right now I am upgrading one machine to Windows 7 with Outlook and trying to move their e-mail accounts and everything over is quite the nightmare.

The goal is to move their POP3 from their old provider to an account I set up over at SolidShellSecurity.com. They set up IMAP accounts for me just wasn't sure how to port their mail up so that it would sync over.

Comment: Are you making a mail server change as well? Otherwise, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, making a mail server change as well.

Comment: Can you provide some details about what the new mail system or solution is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Outlook on the XP machine, connect it to their Exchange account, use Oulook's built in "import everything from Outlook Express" feature:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-your-messages-or-account-from-Outlook-Express-to-Outlook-ca8ecaab-3330-46a1-b925-deac3f3c4359

http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/migratefromoewlm.htm